# How to split a string which contains multiple forward slashes

Tags: ruby

I have a string as given below,

```
./component/unit
```

and need to split to get result as `component/unit` which I will use this as key for inserting hash.

I tried with `.split(/.\//).last` but its giving result as `unit` only not getting `component/unit`.

Comment: `string.split('./')
 => ["", "component/unit"] `

Comment: This is what's sometimes called an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You could use `String#split`, but there are other (arguably better) ways that don't. It would have been better to simply explain what you want to do, so the use of `split` would have been confined to your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, this should help you:

```
string = './component/unit'

string.split('./') 
#=> ["", "component/unit"]

string.split('./').last
#=> "component/unit"
```

Comment: Its working.. my bad I didn't try without using forward slash inside of split. Thanks!

Comment: This will break for "./my/special./file", but i hope your list is sane :)

Answer (score 5):

Your regex was almost fine :

```
split(/\.\//)
```

You need to escape both `.` (any character) and `/` (regex delimiter).

As an alternative, you could just remove the first `'./'` substring :

```
'./component/unit'.sub('./','')
#=> "component/unit"
```

Comment: This solution will break "freaking/path./oups". Probably better would be to anchor the regex on beginning of string ( ^ ) './component./unit'.gsub(/^\.\//,'') - assuming its about filepaths.

Comment: I upvoted your answer : it's pretty clean. But if you name a folder `"freaking/path./oups"`, you deserve any bug which might appear. ;)

Comment: Absoluteley :) But its easily changed by using the ^-anchor, which i think you should include in your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers are fine, but I think you are not really dealing with a `String` here but with a `URI` or `Pathname`, so I would advise you to use these classes if you can. If so, please adjust the title, as it is not about do-it-yourself-regexes, but about proper use of the available libraries.

Link to the ruby doc:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html
and
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html

An example with **Pathname** is:

```
require 'pathname'

pathname = Pathname.new('./component/unit')
puts pathname.cleanpath # => "component/unit"
#    pathname.to_s      # => "component/unit"
```

Whether this is a good idea (and/or using URI would be cool too) also depends on what your real problem is, i.e. what you want to do with the extracted String. As stated, I doubt a bit that you are really intested in Strings.

Comment: Fair comment, it would however be great to see an answer to the question using your approach:)

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Yes you are right, I will provide a "solution". Although I doubt that the question really reflects the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using a positive lookbehind, you could do use regex:

```
reg  = /(?<=\.\/)[\w+\/]+\w+\z/
```

#### Demo

```
str  = './component'
str2 = './component/unit'
str3 = './component/unit/ruby'
str4 = './component/unit/ruby/regex'

[str, str2, str3, str4].each { |s| puts s[reg] }
#component
#component/unit
#component/unit/ruby
#component/unit/ruby/regex
```